# are these firewall settings correct on my freebsd server to allow postfix to pass trough?

Tags: firewall, postfix, freebsd

I'm trying to set a mail server up on my freebsd 7 virtual host. But when I try to send or receive an email the log files tell me something about *connection refused* like this:

```
Feb  8 17:54:42 vps-id2247 postfix/error[29886]: 2A9E044A96F: to=<myemailaddress@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=2165, delays=2165/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
```

Firewall config

```
add allow ip from any to any via lo0
add allow icmp from any to any
add allow tcp from any to me dst-port 22 in
add allow tcp from me 22 to any out
add allow tcp from any to me dst-port 21 in
add allow tcp from me 21 to any out
add allow tcp from any to me dst-port 80 in
add allow tcp from me 80 to any out
add allow tcp from any to me dst-port 25 in
add allow tcp from me 25 to any out
add allow tcp from any to me dst-port 110 in
add allow tcp from me 110 to any out
add allow udp from any to me dst-port 53 in
add allow udp from me 53 to any out
add allow tcp from any to me dst-port 53 in
add allow tcp from me 53 to any out
add allow tcp from any to me dst-port 443 in
add allow tcp from me 443 to any out
add allow tcp from any to me dst-port 10000 in
add allow tcp from me 10000 to any out
add allow tcp from any to me dst-port 143 in
add allow tcp from me 143 to any out
add allow tcp from any to me 49152-65535 in
add allow tcp from me 49152-65535 to any out
add allow ip from any to any out keep-state
add deny ip from any to any
```

So to exude that it's not the firewall I was wondering if these settings are good.
note I'm using the standard ports ( 25, 143 ) and telnet on port 25 tough the domain url says 'hello'.

Comment: your firewall settings seems right, check this http://www.zimbra.com/forums/users/764-connection-refused-port-10024-a.html

Comment: turns out my amavis / clamd was not running thanks!
could you add that as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall settings were ok.

amavis / clamd were not running.

More info here: [link](http://www.zimbra.com/forums/users/764-connection-refused-port-10024-a.html).